# Wingetpos Keeps Adding To The Dimensions

Tags: autohotkey

This is a weird problem.

My GUI keeps getting bigger and bigger!  Here is my function.  Every time I call the function, the values increase just after using WinGetPos.  I call this during the GUI's shutdown procedure.  You can see the report from the messagebox in the comments.

Before the function is called: `x=2248 y=325 w=404 h=400`

```
GetMainWinPosition(){
    global
    msgbox, x=%UIx% y=%UIy% w=%UIw% h=%UIh%  ;x=2248 y=325 w=404 h=400
    WinGetPos, UIx,UIy,UIw,UIh,%apptitle%
    msgbox, x=%UIx% y=%UIy% w=%UIw% h=%UIh%  ;x=2248 y=325 w=412 h=444
}
```

The only thing I can think of that might have any bearing is this, just after GUI, show:

```
Gui, +minsize404x%UIh% +maxsize1000x%UIh%
```

...and the use of Anchor.ahk on some of the controls [edit] Nope, I removed the anchoring and it didn't change anything...

Anyone have a clue?  I'm sure it's a silly thing I am missing.

Comment: Please post the whole script or at least everything of your script that gets executed.

Comment: MCL - well, I can't really do that or I would have, so I just posted the part where the problem lies.  But how can anything else possibly happen between the first and second calls?  My function looks exactly like the one above.

Comment: About a thousand things can happen. For starters, those are global variables, so they could be changed anywhere. Since the msgboxes wait, there could be other threads manipulating the variables or resizing the gui. It is also possible that another process resizes the gui. You may negate all those suggestions, but there's an infinite number of potential origins for your problem. You and me both don't see this code itself producing that kind of error. Provided we're right/not blind, the problem *has* to be somewhere else...

Comment: The only other possibility could be in GUIresize where I am using Anchor.ahk. But this function is only ever called just before `ExitApp`.  Could it be Anchor? I've searched everywhere and can't find anything else referencing the four sizing variables.

Comment: I don't know Anchor, and I'm generally not good at stabbing around in the dark, sorry :/

Comment: What about the +minsize that I added to my question? C'mon, MCL, just a little stab or two...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, I am NOT crazy, and there IS a solution, AND the problem lay *completely* in my plain use WinGetPos command.  See [this thread in the ahkscript forum](http://ahkscript.org/boards/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=892&p=6624#p6624).

Apparently, `WinGetPos` fetches the width and height of the entire window *including* the title bar and the window edges.  This accounts for the change in my window size when I saved the values.

Here is a solution to fetch the width and height without adding in the title bar:

```
VarSetCapacity(rect,16)
DllCall("GetClientRect", "ptr", hwnd, "ptr", &rect)  ;hwnd is the window handle of the gui (hint: Gui, +hwndmyvar)
width := NumGet(rect,8,"int"), height := NumGet(rect,12,"int")
```

And there is a [more elaborate solution here](http://ahkscript.org/boards/viewtopic.php?p=6620#p6620).

Comment: In other words, the initial values of `UIx ...` weren't set by `WinGetPos`! No chance to know that unless you see the rest of the code ;) But I'm glad you figured it out.